# Unix script to automatically insert shebang into perl file

Tags: bash, unix

I am practicing with some Perl scripting and instead of typing the shebang each time I decided to make a basic Unix script that would create a new file with .pl extension and the shebang and then open the file for editing. What I tried was:

```
alias ep "echo '#! /usr/bin/perl' >> perl/\!*.pl; emacs perl/\!*.pl;"
```

But this causes an error if the file doesn't already exist. I found that strange because I thought >> would append or create. So I changed the >> to > and this works but only if the file does not exist. If the file does exist it just crashes with an error. I tried adding an if statement but that also gave errors of syntax error and improper then. What I had for the if was:

```
alias ep "if [ ! -f perl/\!*.pl ] then echo '#! /usr/bin/perl' > perl/\!*.pl fi; emacs perl/\!*.pl;"
```

What am I missing? I am not too familiar with Unix scripting, but have a general knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't want to do it like this; there are a lot of things to take account for (is that really a perl file if it exists already, etc)

you can do it instead directly with emacs

check this out: [emacs skeletons and auto-insert](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=116951)

Comment: This works perfectly, set up an auto insert mapped to .pl files in emacs and changed the script to just add the .pl extension

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you might have `set -C`, also known as `set -o noclobber`.

You can go ahead and clobber the file by using the redirection operator `>|`, or by undoing the option with `set +C`.

Comment: This was the exact problem. I am going to keep the no clobber option set just because I don't want to overwrite a file if it already exists, but thanks for answering my question